# How to create difference of difference contrasts with multcomp

Tags: r

I am building a linear model in R and I have specific planned contrasts I am trying to implement. The model involves an interaction term. I believe I know how to correctly specify the matrix that `glht()` takes in order to provide estimates for the contrasts. However, i'm unsure how to specify interaction planned contrasts in the matrix. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(multcomp)

# Create minimal dataset

set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(response = rnorm(2000), 
                 age = sample(15:60, 2000, replace = TRUE),
                 sex = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each = 1000), 
                 ses = rep(c("L", "LM", "MH", "H"), 500))

# Basic linear model
m1 <- lm(response ~ age + sex * ses, 
         data = df)

summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ age + sex * ses, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3423 -0.6697  0.0044  0.6716  3.2542 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -0.0514746  0.0889766  -0.579    0.563
age           -0.0003435  0.0016934  -0.203    0.839
sexMale        0.0819362  0.0900868   0.910    0.363
sesL           0.0769168  0.0901245   0.853    0.394
sesLM          0.1289027  0.0901339   1.430    0.153
sesMH          0.0681291  0.0900821   0.756    0.450
sexMale:sesL  -0.0661439  0.1274402  -0.519    0.604
sexMale:sesLM -0.0925924  0.1275157  -0.726    0.468
sexMale:sesMH -0.1188700  0.1273978  -0.933    0.351

Residual standard error: 1.007 on 1991 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.001591,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.002421 
F-statistic: 0.3966 on 8 and 1991 DF,  p-value: 0.9229

# Create a matrix of linear combinations
# Here 'H' and 'Female' are the reference categories, 

lc <- rbind("Female:H" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            "Female:L" = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            "Female:LM" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            "Female:MH" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            "Male vs Female difference in L vs H" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
            "Male vs Female difference in LM vs H" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
            "Male vs Female difference in MH vs H" = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))

# Create matrix for the linfct argument in glht()
# One contrast compares the LM to the L category in females
# Another contrast compares the pooled LM and L categories to the H category in females

k <- rbind("Females: LM vs. L" = 
             lc["Female:LM", ] - lc["Female:L", ],
           "Females: Pooled L and LM vs H" =  
             ((lc["Female:LM", ] + lc["Female:L", ]) / 2) - lc["Female:H", ])

c1 <- glht(m1, linfct = k)
s1 <- summary(c1, adjusted(type = "none"))

confint(c1, adjusted(type = "none"))
```

I would like to add to `k`, contrasts:

**Edit**

1. The interaction term that compares the additional difference between L and LM in Men vs. Women
2. The interaction term that compares the additional difference of pooled L and LM categories versus H in Men vs. Women

For example, in the summary output above you would interpret the `sexMale:sesL` term as: The additional difference between L and H, for males vs. females.

This post in CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/design-of-matrix-of-contrasts-in-r was instrumental in getting me this far. However, i'm not sure what linear combinations from `lc` above I should be subtracting in `k` to get the coefficients I want.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This still seems like a statistical problem, not a programming problem. If you know exactly what the contrast should look like but don't know how to create the object, that would be one thing, but if you don't know how to actually test certain hypothesis using contrasts, that seems like a better question for [stats.se], not sure why you asked here instead.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for code and that is why I asked on StackOverflow as opposed to CrossValidated. Although, it is probably a grey area to be honest, since I am also not really understanding how to do something theoretically.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think your `lc` and `k` are correct. The matrix's col-number corresponds to `names(m1$coef)`'s elments number.
`[1] Intercept, [2] age, [3] sexMale, [4] sesL, [5] sesLM, [6] sesMH, [7] sexMale:sesL, [8] sexMale:sesLM, [9] sexMale:sesMH`.
So, `"Female:L" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` means `"Male:H"`, and `"Female:LM" = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` means `Female:L`. You used these difference as `k[,1]`. Attention to `s1`'s Estimate, please.

```
s1
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# Females: LM vs. L == 0             -0.005019   0.090091  -0.056    0.956
# Females: Pooled L and LM vs H == 0  0.079427   0.078038   1.018    0.309

# In fact, you did "sexMale:H vs Female:L".
m1$coef["sesL"] - m1$coef["sexMale"]  # -0.005019421
```

You can get correct matrix by the method the post you linked showed.

```
group <- paste0(df$sex, df$ses)
group <- aggregate(model.matrix(m1) ~ group, FUN=mean)
rownames(group) <- group$group
group <- group[,-1]
group$age <- 0
lc2 <- as.matrix(group)
rownames(lc2)  <- c("Female:H", "Female:L", "Female:LM", "Female:MH", 
                    "Male:H", "Male:L", "Male:LM", "Male:MH")

lc2
          (Intercept) age sexMale sesL sesLM sesMH sexMale:sesL sexMale:sesLM sexMale:sesMH
Female:H            1   0       0    0     0     0            0             0             0
Female:L            1   0       0    1     0     0            0             0             0
Female:LM           1   0       0    0     1     0            0             0             0
Female:MH           1   0       0    0     0     1            0             0             0
Male:H              1   0       1    0     0     0            0             0             0
Male:L              1   0       1    1     0     0            1             0             0
Male:LM             1   0       1    0     1     0            0             1             0
Male:MH             1   0       1    0     0     1            0             0             1
```

```
k2 <- rbind("Females: LM vs. L" = 
              lc2["Female:LM", ] - lc2["Female:L", ],
            "Females: Pooled L and LM vs H" =  
              ((lc2["Female:LM", ] + lc2["Female:L", ]) / 2) - lc2["Female:H", ])

c1_2 <- glht(m1, linfct = k2)
s1_2 <- summary(c1_2, adjusted(type = "none"))

s1_2
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# Females: LM vs. L == 0              0.05199    0.09008   0.577    0.564
# Females: Pooled L and LM vs H == 0  0.10291    0.07807   1.318    0.188

m1$coef["sesLM"] - m1$coef["sesL"]       # 0.05198589
(m1$coef["sesL"] + m1$coef["sesLM"])/2   # 0.1029097
```

#### **[Edited]**

The identity of `sexMale` is the interaction term `Male : H` just to be sure.

```
m2 <- lm(response ~ age + ses + sex:ses , data = df)
summary(m2) # excerpt
# sesH:sexMale   0.0819362  0.0900868   0.910    0.363

summary(m1) # excerpt
# sexMale        0.0819362  0.0900868   0.910    0.363
```

(Note: difference doesn't have an intercept because it is a common term)

```
k3 <- rbind(
  "Male vs Female difference in L vs H"  = 
    (lc2["Male:L",] - lc2["Male:H",]) - (lc2["Female:L",] - lc2["Female:H",]),
  "Male vs Female difference in LM vs H" = 
    (lc2["Male:LM",] - lc2["Male:H",]) - (lc2["Female:LM",] - lc2["Female:H",]),
  "Male vs Female difference in MH vs H" = 
    (lc2["Male:MH",] - lc2["Male:H",]) - (lc2["Female:MH",] - lc2["Female:H",]),
  # above is modified lc[5:7, ], below is what you want
  "Male vs Female difference in LM vs L" = 
    (lc2["Male:LM",] - lc2["Male:L",]) - (lc2["Female:LM",] - lc2["Female:L",]),
  "Male vs Female difference in Pooled L and LM vs H" = 
    ((lc2["Male:L", ] + lc2["Male:LM", ]) / 2 - lc2["Male:H", ])
      - ((lc2["Female:L", ] + lc2["Female:LM", ]) / 2 - lc2["Female:H", ])
)

k3   # I deleted some character, space, digit because of the space and viewability
                 (Intercept) age sexM  sesL sesLM  sesMH sexM:sesL sexM:sesLM sexM:sesMH
M vs F diff in L vs H      0   0    0     0     0      0         1          0          0
M vs F diff in LM vs H     0   0    0     0     0      0         0          1          0
M vs F diff in MH vs H     0   0    0     0     0      0         0          0          1
M vs F diff in LM vs L     0   0    0     0     0      0        -1          1          0
MvsF diff in L&LM vs H     0   0    0     0     0      0       0.5        0.5          0
```

Comment: You're right my '0's are off! Thank you for catching that, it was sloppy of me. The way you do it is definitely better. I appreciate your code, however, I think I may not have been clear. I'm actually looking for the code to make new interaction terms, not main effects as you have given me. As I understand it, the effects you programmed give me the effect of L vs. M in Males. However, I want to know the 'additional difference' of L vs. M in Males vs. Females.  I'll edit my original post and re-word to make it clearer.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I was trying everything to figure out how to do this. Makes sense now that I see what you've done.

Comment: @RNB; I'm glad that I could assist you (I edited a few typo).